# Primefaces 3.5 JSF 2.1 ClassNotFoundException on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i try to migrate my JSF 2.1 Webapp to the Google App engine.

Everything runs ok in local dev mode, deployment is also ok on GAE, but when i try to access any page i get HTTP Code 500. The Logfile shows that there's a ClassNotFoundException:

```
INFO: com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ELResolverInitPhaseListener populateFacesELResolverForJsp: JSF1027: [null] 
      The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container.
WARNING: populateFacesELResolverForJsp: JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container.
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.RuntimeException:  
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:268)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:438)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:480)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:487)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:774)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$DoInTraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:751)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:342)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:334)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:484)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I already tried to deploy the corresponding library jaxp-ri-1.4.jar which had no effect.

Some more Information about my Configuration and third party libs:

```
- Mojarra JSF 2.1.12
- Primefaces 3.5
- Primefaces Extensions 
- Prettyfaces 3.3.3
- Ebay Finding Api
- STATE_SAVING_METHOD set to 'client'
-  i use EL 2.2 form jboss seam  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you take a look at this: http://javadocs.wordpress.com/2009/10/17/mojarra-jsf-2-0-rc2-and-google-app-engine-sdk-1-2-6/#more-242 ?

Comment: Yes i checked this out. I have implemented the modfified WebConfiguration.java. I think there were old files included in the lib folder. I rebuild everything and uploaded again. Same Problem, but if i access the App with the url: 1.version.myapp.appspot.com - It work's!

Comment: Okay it does not work. The page is now rendered, but on any ajax request i get the response:
<partial-response><error><error-name>class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[Could not initialize class com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl]]></partial-response>

Comment: Does your faces-config.xml has: <application>
 <el-resolver>org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>

Comment: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ElementNSImpl", you need to add  jaxp-ri jar file.

Comment: Ok i added jaxp-ri.jar again. The page is rendering, but when an action is called the http response contains: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl is a restricted class! What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging i found out that the eBay Finding API causes the Problem, as it uses SOAP for service calls. Without calling the eBay Api, everything runs ok.

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl is a restricted Class
```

Seems like the eBay finding API is not compatible with the Google App Engine, as it uses JAX-WS.